# Domain and Range of Function $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$.

Tags: functions

$\bullet$ What is the domain and range of function $f(x)=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ ?

$\bullet$ Let $D= \sqrt {1-x^2}$

Since $f$ is a square root function and since the argument of $f$ is $(x-D)$ need : $x-D\geq0$.

$x-D\geq0\iff x\geq D\iff D\leq x$

$\bullet$ Using the definition of $D$, this means that :

$\sqrt {1-x^2} \leq x$

$\iff 1-x^2 \leq x^2$

$ \iff 1 \leq 2x^2$

$\iff x^2 \geq \frac 12$

$\iff \sqrt{x^2} \geq \sqrt {\frac 12}$

$\iff |x| \geq \frac 14$

$\iff (x \geq \frac 14) \lor (x \leq -\frac 14)$

So , domain $(f) = (-\infty; -\frac 14] \cup [\frac 14; + \infty)$

$\bullet$ This answer is not correct.

Symbolab calculator says that I have to add the condition : $-1\leq x\leq 1$

But it seemed to me  I had already  taken this condition into account when I solved the inequality involving expression $D= \sqrt {1-x^2}$.

Can you please explain what I do miss here?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Any thoughts yourself? It is mandatory to give your own thoughts on questions. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Are complex numbers allowed?

Comment: @JB King NO complex numbers are not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

We need $|x|\le 1$, else $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not defined. But $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ clearly is undefined if $x$ is negative. For it to be defined, we need $x\ge 0$ and $x\ge \sqrt{1-x^2}$, or equivalently $x^2\ge 1-x^2$, or equivalently $x\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Thus the (natural) domain is all reals $x$ such that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\le x\le 1$.

I will leave the range to you, with a large hint: the function is increasing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I got it where I was going wrong. Range is 0≤x≤1.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that is the range. Depending on how careful you need to be in your justifications, you may need to *prove* the function is increasing (easy, $x$ i increasing and $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is decreasing) and mention the Intermediate Value Theorem in showing the function takes on *all* values between $0$ and $1$. The IVT applies because the function is continuous. Or maybe, sadly, you are just expected to come up with answers.